# How to skip header row in csv using C++

Tags: c++, csv

In my scenario,I need to create a parameters file using CSV .Every row means a config-data,the first field of the row treated as the header,using as a identifier. The format of CSV like below will be easy for me to parse:

```
1,field1,field2,field3,field4　// 1 indicated the TARGET that the other fields will be writted to.
1,field1,field2,field3,field4
2,field1,field2,field3,field4
2,field1,field2,field3,field4........
```

But it's not friendly to users.So,I define a csv file like below:

```
HeaderLine_Begin,1
field1,field2,field3,field4
field1,field2,field3,field4
HeaderLine_Begin,2
field1,field2,field3,field4
field1,field2,field3,field4
```

means,every row is the data will be writted to the target by the HeaderLine_Begin.I just separate the ID from the real data.
Then,I create a struct like this:

```
    enum myenum
    {
      ON,OFF,NOCHANGE
    };

    struct Setting
    {
      int TargetID;

      string field1;
      string field2;
      myenum field3;
      myenum field4;    
    };
```

I knew how to write some code for reading csv line by line like below

```
filename +=".csv";

std::ifstream file(filename.c_str());
std::string line;

while ( file.good() )
{       
    getline ( file, line, '\n' ); // read a line until last 
    if(line.compare(0,1,"#") == 0) // ignore the comment line
        continue;

    ParseLine();// DONE.Parse the line if it's header row OR data row           
}

file.close(); // close file
```

What I want to do is to create a list like vetor settings to keep the data.The flow should be,like,find the first headerID1,then find the next line.If the next line is dataline,treat it as the dataline belong to headerID1.If the next line is another headerID,loop again.

The problem is,there are no such std::getnextline(int lineIndex) for me to fetch the rows after I found the headerRow.

Comment: You could start by checking if the line is a header row or a data row. But you probably know that. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: how to getline() just for data row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input loop should be more like:

```
int id = -1;
while (getline(file, line))
{
     if (line.empty() || line[0] == '#')
         continue;
     if (starts_with_and_remove(line, "HeaderLine_Begin,"))
         id = boost::lexical_cast<int>(line); // or id = atoi(line.c_str())
     else
     {
         assert(id != -1);
         ...parse CSV, knowing "id" is in effect...
     }
}
```

With:

```
bool stats_with_and_remove(std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.compare(0, rhs.size(), lhs) == 0)  // rhs.size() > lhs.size() IS safe
    {
        lhs.erase(0, rhs.size());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but I am not allowed to use boost lib in my solution.

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast` is really only syntactic sugar, and easy to implement yourself, at least for the casts to and from string.  C++11 has `std::stoi`, etc. which can be used as well.

Comment: @fanshaoer: as per the comment, you can replace the `lexical_cast<>` line with `id = atoi(line.c_str());` if you don't want to use boost, but unlike `lexical_cast` it won't throw an exception if the line doesn't have a valid number - instead the `id` will be set to 0.

Comment: @TonyD If you want to use the C functions, `strtol` would be the correct one, as it does support error handling.

Comment: @TonyD Thank you.Ok,means I have to implement the exception logic by myself.it works,except the header row,all data row can be printed out row by row.But I still don't know how to put the headerId and headerID's data into the vector<Setting>

Comment: @JamesKanze: true... just more tedious to call, and if 0 is not a valid id in your file format, it suffices to "assert(id != 0)" or throw on 0.

Comment: @fanshaoer: I can't tell you a lot about that without seeing any of your CSV-parsing code ;-). In my code above, the "id" variable will be holding the current `id` value that should be used in the `...parse CSV...` code: for example, you might do something like `std::vector<Value> values; values.push_back(Setting(id)); csv_pushback(line);` - the exact solution depends on the CSV parsing function and `Setting` type.  At worst (adding at position 0 in a vector is slow), if you have a `vector` of other fields, try a `values.insert(0, Setting(id));` after doing the CSV parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use regular expressions:

```
std::string line;
int currentId = 0;
while ( std::getline( source, line ) ) {
    trimCommentsAndWhiteSpace( line );
    static std::regex const header( "HeaderLine_Begin,(\\d+)" );
    std::smatch match;
    if ( line.empty() ) {
        //  ignore
    } else if ( std::regex_match( line, match, header ) ) {
        std::istringstream s( match[ 1 ] );
        s >> currentId;
    } else {
        //  ...
    }
}
```

I regularly use this strategy to parse `.ini` files, which pose
the same problem: section headers have a different syntax to
other things.

`trimCommentsAndWhiteSpace` can be as simple as:

```
void
trimCommentsAndWhiteSpace( std::string& line )
{
    if ( !line.empty() && line[0] == '#' ) {
        line = "";
    }
}
```

It's fairly easy to expand it to handle end of line comments as
well, however, and it's usually a good policy (in contexts like
this) to trim leading and trailing whitespace---trailing
especially, since a human reader won't see it when looking at
the file.

Alternatively, of course, you could use a regular expression for
the lines you want to treet as comments ("\s*#.*"); this works
well with your current definition, but doesn't really extend
well for end of line comments, especially if you want to allow
`#` in quoted strings in your fields.

And one final comment: your loop is incorrect.  You don't test
that `getline` succeeded before using its results, and
`file.good()` may return true even if there is nothing more to
read.  (`file.good()` is one of those things that are there for
historical reasons; there's no case where it makes sense to use
it.)